# ListBox handling in wpf application in visual studio

Tags: c#

I have 3 listboxes,3 texboxes,3buttons in my window ,when i enter data from listbox1 into the textbox1 and click button or enter then the other 2 listbox items of same index should appear on the other 2 textboxes.

this is the code written till now

```
private void Get_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int x = listbox1.SelectedIndex;
    listbox2.SelectedIndex = x;
    listbox3.SelectedIndex = x;

    ListBoxItem lb1 = (listbox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
    tb1.Text = lb1.Content.ToString();


    ListBoxItem lb2 = (listbox2.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
    tb2.Text = lb2.Content.ToString();

    ListBoxItem lb3 = (listbox3.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
    tb3.Text = lb3.Content.ToString();


}


private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int x = listbox1.SelectedIndex;
    listbox2.SelectedIndex = x;
    listbox3.SelectedIndex = x;

    listbox1.Items.Add(tb1.Text);
    listbox2.Items.Add(tb2.Text);
    listbox3.Items.Add(tb3.Text);

}

private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int x = listbox1.SelectedIndex;
    listbox2.SelectedIndex = x;
    listbox3.SelectedIndex = x;

    listbox1.Items.RemoveAt(listbox1.Items.IndexOf(listbox1.SelectedItem));
    listbox2.Items.RemoveAt(listbox2.Items.IndexOf(listbox2.SelectedItem));
    listbox3.Items.RemoveAt(listbox3.Items.IndexOf(listbox3.SelectedItem));


}
```

Comment: Is this winforms or WPF your title says one thing, but your tag says another?

Comment: just to clarify: the selected index of listbox1 should be reflected by the other two `ListBox` controls? So When `listbox1.SelectedIndex` is e.g. '3', so should the other indices be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're after, but I *think* you're trying to get the text in tb1 to be the driver instead of selecting from listbox1. I've added some simple code to the Get_Click event:

```
private void Get_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListBoxItem lbi in listbox1.Items)    //new code
    {                                              //new code
        if (lbi.Content.ToString() == tb1.Text)    //new code
        {                                          //new code
            lbi.IsSelected = true;                 //new code
            break;                                 //new code
        }                                          //new code
    }                                              //new code

    int x = listbox1.SelectedIndex;
    listbox2.SelectedIndex = x;
    listbox3.SelectedIndex = x;

    //ListBoxItem lb1 = (listbox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);   //updated
    //tb1.Text = lb1.Content.ToString();                          //updated

    ListBoxItem lb2 = (listbox2.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
    tb2.Text = lb2.Content.ToString();

    ListBoxItem lb3 = (listbox3.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
    tb3.Text = lb3.Content.ToString();
}
```

Is this the kind of thing you're after?

Comment: i'm new to c#,can u please explain me this code ?                     foreach (ListBoxItem lbi in listbox1.Items)
        {
            if (lbi.Content.ToString() == tb1.Text)
            {
                lbi.IsSelected = true;
            }
        }

Comment: @user2810060 with apologies if the following is too simplified... The _foreach_ loop simply goes through each item in _listbox1_ (identifying each item using local variable _lbi_) and compares it against the text you've entered in tb1 (using the _if_). Once it's found a match then the relevant item gets selected (_lbi.IsSelected = true_) - you _could_ actually exit the _foreach_ loop here by using _break;_ if there's a lot of remaining rows. The rest of the code is yours, noting that my code does not cater for errors such as finding no matches.